# Machine Learning Services fails from Secondary Node of SQL Failover Cluster Instance

Tags: sql-server, python, r, sql-server-2022, failover-cluster-instance

There was a planned cluster failover to the secondary node of our FCI. Afterwards, `sp_execute_external_script` stopped working.
Examples with error messages are below:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @script=N'print(R.version)',@language=N'R';
GO
```

> Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 0   Unable to communicate with the
> runtime for 'R' script for request id:
> 4B918DE5-B534-4F35-8723-34F818536F68. Please check the requirements of
> 'R' runtime.  STDERR message(s) from external script:
>
> SQLSatellite Run() failed.  Error code:0x80004004.  Error in eval(ei,
> envir) :          SQLSatellite Run() failed.  Error code:0x80004004.  Calls:
> runScriptFile -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
> Execution halted

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @script=N'import sys;print(sys.version)',@language=N'Python'
GO
```

> Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 3 Unable to communicate with the
> runtime for 'Python' script for request id:
> D1397DA5-79FD-4C4A-891C-C01E436FA20F. Please check the requirements of
> 'Python' runtime. STDERR message(s) from external script:
>
> SQLSatellite Run() failed.  Error code:0x80004004. SqlSatelliteCall
> error: SQLSatellite Run() failed.  Error code:0x80004004. STDOUT
> message(s) from external script:  SqlSatelliteCall function failed.
> Please see the console output for more information. Traceback (most
> recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py",
> line 608, in rx_sql_satellite_call
> rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line
> 375, in rx_native_call
> ret = px_call(functionname, params) RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.

Other notes that may or may not be relevant:

- In my mind, the setup and configuration of `R` and `Python` is the same on both cluster nodes. (But I'm fallible.)
- The logon account for the SQL Server Launchpad service is a domain account on both nodes (same account).
- Whether it's `R` or `Python`, `sp_execute_external_script` runs for 60 seconds before erroring out.

I reviewed the documentation for the following two articles. I'm not seeing anything that is missing or out of order: 
[Install SQL Server 2022 Machine Learning Services (Python and R) on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install-sql-2022?view=sql-server-ver16)
[Known issues for Python and R in SQL Server Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/troubleshooting/known-issues-for-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver16)

More documentation:
[Create a login for SQLRUserGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/security/create-a-login-for-sqlrusergroup?view=sql-server-ver16): This suggested there is supposed to be a login for `SQLRUserGroup`, which is a local machine group account. However, `sp_execute_external_script` works on the primary node. And there is no `[NodeA\SQLRUserGroup]` login. Nonetheless, I thought I'd try creating the `[NodeB\SQLRUserGroup]` for the secondary node. No additional permissions were granted to the login, and it is not a member of any server roles (except for [public])

```
USE [master]
CREATE LOGIN [NodeB\SQLRUserGroup] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
```

**My Question**
What could be causing `sp_execute_external_script` to fail on the secondary node (NodeB)?